# GetAddrInfo на Windows и Linux

Tags: c++, c, winsock, winsock2

Подскажите пожалуйста, насколько я понял к примеру функция GetAddrInfo - это функция из стандарта сокетов Беркли, к примеру ее описание я нашел ее в rfc3493:

> Protocol-Independent Nodename and Service Name Translation   nt
> getaddrinfo(const char *nodename, const char *servname,
> const struct addrinfo *hints, struct addrinfo **res);

Однако в Winsock есть функция GetAddrInfoW - типа юникодный UTF-16 аналог.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что код написанный с помощью GetAddrInfoW на Linux не запустится, так как там просто нет такой расширенной функции ?

И если нет, то как тогда в Linux`е делать запросы к DNS юникодных Http-ссылок, ну к примеру содержащих китайские символы ?

Или const char *nodename - можно указывать в разных кодировках ? Как в национальной кодировке, так и в UTF-8 ? А DNS типа сам разберется с кодировками ? Он может все кодировки поддерживать - типа и UTF-16 и CP-1251 и/или CP-866 ... ?

Comment: Преобразуйте имя домена в punycode и отправляйте запрос в таком виде.

Comment: В DNS в принципе не бывает юникода, поэтому и проблемы такой не существует. Вместо юникода используется вышеупомянутый punycode

Comment: @andreymal, я даже не знал про punycode. Правильно ли я понял, что любое доменное имя состоящее из символов отличных от ASCII - в итоге все равно преобразуются в массив символов ASCII и в таком виде уже отправляются на DNS ? Тогда получается, что ОС сама преобразует не стандартные доменные имена к punycode`у ?

Comment: а ещё в glibc у `getaddrinfo()` есть флаг `AI_IDN`, при указании которого, доменное имя с не-ascii символами, будет преобразовано самой libc из текущей локали...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а если доменное имя с не-ascii символами записано не в текущей локали ? К примеру массив char`ов в utf-8 китайскими символами.

Comment: @Optimus1, почти на все современных (~пост-2005) linux-системах локаль по умолчанию — utf-8... нормально предполагать, что все строки от пользователя будут в системной локали... что касатся более странных вариантов типа «строка с не-ascii символами в исходниках», то гарантированного варианта как с таким работать я не подскажу...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Локаль по-умолчанию на линкус в 2021 по-прежнему посиксная...

Comment: @user7860670, в glibc posix'ная... во всех дистрибутивах linux — utf-8...

Comment: *"во всех дистрибутивах linux — utf-8."* - сильное заявление... И если его проверить, взяв например самую тривиальную убунту 18.04, то выяснится, что неверное, от слова совсем. Так как для добавления utf-8 там надо ставить несколько пакетов, а затем пошаманить с их конфигурированием и настройкой окружения.

Comment: Локаль — это свойство процесса, причём тут дистрибутивы или мифические значения по умолчанию? Всё зависит от соответствующих настроек.